# Does the attribute media in <link> prevent render blocking?

Tags: html, css

Assuming a browser window of 500px, and following code:

```
<link media="only screen and (max-width: 480px)" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

I'm sure the browser loads the style.css resource, but does it blocks the render of the page even the device is not interested in that style, or it load asynchronously?